# Past simple transforms to past perfect?

Tags: past-perfect, simple-past

I had a leg injury. Past simple.
I had had a leg injury. Past perfect.

But if I add word "until" past simple transforms to past perfect:
I had a leg injury until I was 15.
Is this sentence correct?

So, I'm stuck. Seems that sentence means the same as
I had had a leg injury until I was 15.

Comment: Surely an injury is a one-off event? You could say _I suffered from the effects of my leg injury until I was 15_.

Answer (score 1):

They do mean the same thing. But without further context, the use of the past perfect in your second example is unnecessary, because there is no clear reference to some action in the past tense which is preceded by the leg injury.

For instance, in this example sentence:
My running coach *was shocked* to learn that I *had had* a leg injury until I was 15.

The coach was shocked at some time in the past, and it is  clear that the leg injury occurred in the more distant past because of the use of the past perfect.